# How can i fix subdivision surface + bevel modifier issue with modifiers

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I am wondering if it's possible to get rid of artefacts after using a bevel and subdivision surface automatically by using modifiers.

I get those artefacts:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try meshing your object like this:
[image]

See how are the edges/faces here?
Is a little bit different.